# Does not have internet access after changing IP address

Tags: networking, internet

I have changed my IP address by using this method...

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 up  (which is the IP address that I want)
route add default gw 192.168.1.1
echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1"> /etc/resolv.conf
```

I successfully changed my IP address but after changing I cannot connect to the Internet.

Comment: Gotta set it up in your router as well. Connect to your router's control panel and look around for static IP settings.

Comment: Why did you set your gateway and IP address to the same thing?  Is your computer going to be the router?

Comment: Even with your new change to here, your IP address and Gateway are not in the same subnet.  They would both have to match `192.168.1.xxx` or `192.168.0.xxx`.

Comment: Manually changing IP address might not be supported by the network. What are you trying to achieve actually? (You should read about [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).)

Answer (score 2):

Your IP and gateway are not in the same subnet.

Your router will have a gateway LAN address of 192.168.1.1 or something along those lines (could be 192.168.0.1, 10.10.0.1, 10.10.1.1, etc.). If you set a static IP on your device it needs to match that format.

With a 255.255.255.0 mask only the final number will vary from device to device.